# How do I override the websocket.textBufferSize property of an embedded Tomcat with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, websocket

The org.apache.tomcat.websocket.textBufferSize property is mentioned in Tomcat 8.5's [websocket how-to](https://ci.apache.org/projects/tomcat/tomcat85/docs/web-socket-howto.html). It says:

> The default buffer size for text messages is 8192 bytes. This may be changed for a web application by setting the servlet context initialization parameter org.apache.tomcat.websocket.textBufferSize to the desired value in bytes.

I am using an embedded Tomcat through Spring Boot and need to modify that init-param. I've looked through the [common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) managed by Spring Boot and did not find that parameter in there. I've placed it in application.yaml as (for example) `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.textBufferSize: 40000`, and got a message from Tomcat: `The decoded text message was too big for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages`.

These are needed to be complete messages, not partial ones.

I'm hoping I can change that property to a higher value than the default that Tomcat has placed (8192).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the desired size on the Session (javax.websocket.Session) object in the @OnOpen handler like **session.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(20000)**.